# Hide wheel completely

Tags: wheelnav.js

I would like to hide a wheelnav completely. So far I've been hiding each individual slice using the `hide()` method. This was a suggestion I found [here](https://github.com/softwaretailoring/wheelnav/issues/31), but would also require me to loop through the items and show them again later. I also stumbled across a suggestion to call `spreadWheel()` on the wheels themselves. I liked this idea, as the animation for closing are played. However, This doesn't hide the spreader. If I have a title, icons, colored circle etc. as a spreader, this will still show on both 'solutions'. Is there any way I can hide everything in one call?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your needs outside the wheelnav.

When a spreader disappears at the end of closing how can you use that spreader for an opening?

Here is a possible solution:

```
switchButton.onclick = function () {
    if (wheelDiv.style.display === "none") {
        wheelDiv.style.display = "block";
    }
    else {
        wheelDiv.style.display = "none";
    }
    wheel.spreadWheel();
}
```

Comment: I actually don't want the user to be  able to use the spreader, but rather handle it all from code in javascript. I have multiple wheels, subwheels if you like, and I only want to show the active one. When I hide the other wheels, they still have leftovers in the form of their spreader. Instead I would like to hide them entirely, and only have them appear whenever the user navigates to that wheel using the slices if that makes sense. EDIT: I will give your solution a try later today, thanks.

Comment: Hello again Gábor, your solution doesn't work for me unfortunately. My wheelnavs are sharing the same div container. The first wheelnav is created by passing the div id, and the following wheels are passed the raphael property of the first wheel as shown on the documentation for having multiple wheels on your website. Therefore if I hide the div, all of the wheels will be hidden unless I'm misunderstanding your suggestion. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Basically, this library built for a simple wheel. Therefore my solution aims to that. Multiple wheels are possible, but this is not a default functionality and has some issues.